# Web wordgame data saving in python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, cgi

I have a word game as a web-page made in html, css and js.

1. User input his name in input form.
2. User presses "ready" button after playing.
3. Program sends the information about the session to the server.
4. Server saves this information in a file.

The information saves correctly, but after user presses "ready" button web page updates.
Is it possible to send the information to the server without updating the web-page?

```
<form method="GET" action="../cgi-bin/game.py">
    <input type="submit" value = "Ready!" id="readyBut">
    <input type="hidden" name="op" value="save"></input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible with AJAX. Check out jQuery's [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method.

Specifically, if you want to send a GET request, you can also use the [get()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_get.asp) method.

Here's how it should look on the client side:

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" value = "Ready!" id="readyBut">
    <input type="hidden" name="op" value="save"></input>
</form>

<script>
    $("readyButton").click(function(){
      $.get("../cgi-bin/game.py",function(data,status){ // use whatever url is relevant
        console.log(data); // data is whatever your python script returns.
      });
    });
</script>
```

Although if you want to send data to the script, I'd highly recommend using the $.post() method.

Comment: And not absolutely possible with python?

Comment: You are using python at the server end. That script will remain as is (and return a JSON string with whatever data you need to continue with the game).